# Automatically wrap previous word in DIV with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to wrap my previous string (before each comma) in div tags, much like the tags search on stackoverflow.

this is a keyword, another, keyword

```
this is a keyword
another
keyword
```

To do this, how do i detect the comma key is pressed?

```
keyup(function(e) {});
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Liamatvenn/QStkd/1472/)

Comment: Check `e.which`'s value.

Comment: If this is actually to make tags, I'd recommend the TagIt plugin.

Comment: use e.which and find the keycode from http://whatthekeycode.com/

Answer (score 1):

This should work...

http://jsfiddle.net/2cWvC/1/

```
$("input").keydown(function(e){
    var keys, html;
    if (e.keyCode == 188) { 
        keys = this.value.split(',');

        html = $.map(keys, function(key) {
            return '<div>' + key + '</div>';
        }).join('');     

        $('#result').html(html);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you mean something like this: ([working jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/QStkd/1474/))

```
$('input').keyup(function(e) {
     $('#result').html('');
    var valueArr = $(this).val().split(',');

    for(var i=0; i<valueArr.length; i++){
        $('#result').append('<div>'+valueArr[i]+'</div>')
    }
});
```

This will break the string inside your input to parts by the ',' delimiter and assign each part to a `<div>`

Comment: When possible, it's better to not touch the DOM for every key in your array. The better thing to do would be to create a string for the new value and append it to the result at the end. :)